# Apache Mina SSHD Authentication and Encryption

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, sshd

I set up an SSH Server as an SFTP Server with Apache Mina SSHD. Is there any difference in the way the connection is encrypted when using either the password authenticator or the public key authenticator? Or are they all about authentication and it is my decision which one I want to use?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference between the connection encryption (check the RFC describing SSH protocol). It is always encrypted using AES or some symmetric cipher. The key is established during (Diffie-Hellman) key exchange, which happens even before authentication.

The difference is only in the authentication method later and you can consider public key authentication more secure.